# Logic question. Need help

Tags: logic, optimization

This classroom could use a new paint job. The resources must be assigned to do the job but a schedule needs to be determined based on past history (BOE)

```
Resource A and B together have done a similar job in 10 days

Resource A and C together have done a similar job in 15 days

Resource B and C together have done a similar job in 30 days
```

• Only one resource can be made available and you want to assign the most efficient one.

Calculate how long would it take each resource to paint the room individually and determine the most efficient resource

Comment: Can you show us some of your own thoughts?  Surely it should be clear who is the best resource, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously resource A is the most effective. A will complete job in 15 days, B - in 30, C -... well, I'll leave this one to you